# Filter array object based on specific condition -typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, linq

I want to filter array object `data` where `Failed` count greater than 0. My below code is NOT working

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.employeeService.getProducts().subscribe((data:any) => {
  console.log(data);

  this.products=data.Products.array.forEach(element => {
   i=>i.Failed>0
  });

  });
}
```

These are classes for Products

```
export class Productlist {
    Products :Array<Products>
    Page:string
    PageSize:string       
}

export class Products{
    Platform:string
    Compliant:string
    Failed:string
}
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` is just iterating over all elements in the array, but does not perform any action (like filter) to the array at all.

There's a specific `.filter` method provided for [Arrays in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Usually, you would use it like so:

```
this.products = data.Products.filter((product) => product.Failed > 0);
```

But given your provided class definitions your `Failed` property holds a string. I assume it contains a number, so you will have to convert the string to a number first to make it comparable.

```
this.products = data.Products.filter((product) => Number.parseInt(product.Failed) > 0)
```

That also assumes the string only holds integer values, no float values.